# C++ returning class object through multiple function

Tags: c++, function, visual-c++, pointers

I'm trying to pass custom object (`TextureInfos`) through multiples functions.

The call is:

```
TextureManager::Instance()->getTextureInfos("TEST",0)
```

TextureManager.cpp

```
TextureInfos& TextureManager::getTextureInfos(std::string key, int id) 
{
    TextureSet textureSet = textureSets[key];

    return textureSet.getTextureInfos(id);
}
```

TextureSet .cpp

```
TextureInfos& TextureSet::getTextureInfos(int id) 
{   
    sf::Texture texture;
    sf::IntRect rect;

    if (id < tileCount) {
        int x = (id % maxCol) * tileWidth;
        int y = (id / maxCol) * tileHeight;
        rect.left = x;
        rect.top = y;
        rect.width = tileWidth;
        rect.height = tileHeight;
    }

    TextureInfos *textureInfos = new TextureInfos(texture,rect);

    return textureInfos;
}
```

I'm new to C++ and I think I miss something with the operator "&" and "*" etc. Because this code does not work for the moment...

Any help?
Thanks a lot.

EDIT:

Ok so the purpose of this code is to get a `TextureInfos` object at the end of the process. For this, I need to call the `getTextureInfos` method from TextureManager which also call `getTextureInfos` from `TextureSet`.

Here is the complete code for TextureManager.cpp

```
#include "TextureManager.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

TextureManager TextureManager::m_TextureManager;
const std::string basePath="Assets/Graphics";

#pragma region Constructor
TextureManager::TextureManager()
{
    textureSets.clear();
}

TextureManager::~TextureManager()
{

}
#pragma endregion

#pragma region Textures management

// Charge un set de texture a partir d'un nom de fichier
void TextureManager::LoadTextureset(std::string fileName,std::string key) {

    TextureSet textureSet;
    textureSet.init(basePath + fileName, key);

    textureSets[key] = textureSet;
}

// Récupère une texture de la liste
TextureInfos TextureManager::getTextureInfos(std::string key, int id) 
{
    TextureSet textureSet = textureSets[key];

    return textureSet.getTextureInfos(id); // HERE I GET AN ERROR
}

#pragma endregion
```

The line which is commented at the end is where i got an error:

```
no suitable user-defined conversion from "TextureInfos" to "TextureInfos" exists.
```

And for TextureSet.cpp:

```
#include "TextureSet.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "RapidXML\rapidxml.hpp"
#include "Debug.h"

const std::string basePath="Assets/Graphics";

using namespace rapidxml;

#pragma region Constructor
TextureSet::TextureSet()
{

}

TextureSet::~TextureSet()
{

}
#pragma endregion

void TextureSet::init(std::string l_filePath,std::string l_key)
{
    filePath = l_filePath;
    key = l_key;

    // On détermine les URLs des fichiers
    std::string setDescriptorPath = filePath + ".xml";
    std::string setTilesetPath = filePath + ".png";

    // On charge la texture
    if (!textureSet.loadFromFile(setTilesetPath))
        throw "ça load pas";

    // On lis le xml
    std::ifstream xmlDescriptor(setDescriptorPath);
    if(!xmlDescriptor)
        throw "Could not load tileset: " + setDescriptorPath;

    std::string xmlDescriptorContents;
    {
        std::string line;
        while(std::getline(xmlDescriptor, line))
            xmlDescriptorContents += line;
    }

    std::vector<char> xmlData = std::vector<char>(xmlDescriptorContents.begin(), xmlDescriptorContents.end());
    xmlData.push_back('\0');

    //Create a parsed document with &xmlData[0] which is the char*
    xml_document<> doc;
    doc.parse<parse_no_data_nodes>(&xmlData[0]);

    //Get the root node
    xml_node<>* root = doc.first_node();
    xml_node<>* imagefile = root->first_node("params");

    maxRow = atoi(imagefile->first_attribute("maxRow")->value());
    maxCol = atoi(imagefile->first_attribute("maxCol")->value());
    tileWidth = atoi(imagefile->first_attribute("tileWidth")->value());
    tileHeight = atoi(imagefile->first_attribute("tileHeight")->value());
    tileCount = atoi(imagefile->first_attribute("tileCount")->value());
}

TextureInfos TextureSet::getTextureInfos(int id) 
{   
    sf::Texture texture;
    sf::IntRect rect;

    if (id < tileCount) {
        int x = (id % maxCol) * tileWidth;
        int y = (id / maxCol) * tileHeight;
        rect.left = x;
        rect.top = y;
        rect.width = tileWidth;
        rect.height = tileHeight;
    }

    TextureInfos textureInfos(texture,rect);

    return textureInfos;
}
```

TextureInfos.h

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include <string>

class TextureInfos
{

private:

protected:

public:
    TextureInfos(sf::Texture& l_texture, sf::IntRect l_textureRect);
    ~TextureInfos();

    sf::Texture& texture;
    sf::IntRect textureRect;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't work because it doesn't even compile. The reason it doesn't compile is because you try to return a pointer as a reference. A pointer and a reference are two different things.

For a quick, simple and dirty fix, change the return types from from `TextureInfos&` to `TextureInfos*`.

---

The quick fix outlined above is "dirty" because as you are using the code you will have a memory leak (you allocate memory with `new` but don't free it).

That can be solved two ways: Either return *by value* instead of using pointers/references. Or use smart pointers such as [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. Is "by value" meaning to pass my class object in the parameters of the function, like a reference?

Comment: @ApheX No, just return it without pointers or references, so return type as plain `TextureInfos` and then declare the variable as plain `textureInfos` and not a pointer.

Comment: Thank you, I'll use plain object instead of a pointer. But I got another error when doing this. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you can avoid the use of dynamic memory allocation just edit your `TextureSet::getTextureInfos` to return a new stack object by value (notice that there will be a Return Value Optimization if you are worried about efficiency):

```
TextureInfos TextureSet::getTextureInfos(int id) 
{   
    // ...
    return TextureInfos(texture, rect);
}
```

Otherwise, if you really need dynamic allocation, use an `std::shared_ptr` to avoid memory leaks:

```
std::shared_ptr<TextureInfos> TextureSet::getTextureInfos(int id) 
{   
    // ...
    return std::make_shared<TextureInfos>(texture, rect);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jefffrey! I did not know about this memory allocation trick. But I still get an error in TextureManager, as explained in my edit of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

According to your object naming I am assuming that you want to have a set of objects in your TextureSet. I would therefore suggest to add a private variable to your Object, and test new get requests against this object. You can then safely return a reference to a member.

Answer (score 0):

One think that looks very worrying is that `TextureInfos` holds a *reference* to a texture, and you construct one from a passed reference.

```
TextureInfos(sf::Texture& l_texture, sf::IntRect l_textureRect);

sf::Texture& texture;
sf::IntRect textureRect;
```

Assuming the constructor does something like this

```
TextureInfos(sf::Texture& l_texture, sf::IntRect l_textureRect) : 
  texture(l_texture),
  textureRect(l_textureRect)
{
}
```

... then you are entering a world of much pain. Look at GetTextureInfos() to see why:-

```
TextureInfos& TextureSet::getTextureInfos(int id) 
{   
    sf::Texture texture;
    sf::IntRect rect;

    ...

    TextureInfos *textureInfos = new TextureInfos(texture,rect);

    return textureInfos;
}
```

Ignoring the obvious issue that this will likely leak the returned object, you have the major problem that the returned object holds a reference to `texture` - but `texture` has gone out of scope so is no longer valid!

I can't propose a simple solution - but you need to make sure that you understand the lifetime management and ownership issues of the objects you're creating. Smart pointers (and returning entire objects rather than references) are usually key parts of this.